# NSURLSessionUploadTask timing out

Tags: swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking to upload video files to a server and I'm getting the uploads timing out  almost every time I try to upload files.

I'm trying to upload multiple files at the same time, so far the max I have tried is 2 because they keep timing out.

Relevant Code:

```
        for i in 0 ... 2 {
            let filePath : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "filepathgoeshere")

            let tempFilename = String(format: "%f", NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
            let tempFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(tempFilename)")

            let request = AFHTTPRequestSerializer().multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: getAPIURL(), parameters: parameters, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData : AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
                formData.appendPartWithFileURL(filePath, name: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "video/mp4", error: nil)
                }, error: nil)

            // Work around for problem with multi-part requests not giving a content-length and being rejected by S3
            // See: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1398
            AFHTTPRequestSerializer().requestWithMultipartFormRequest(request, writingStreamContentsToFile: tempFileUrl, completionHandler: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var manager : AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

                var progress : NSProgress? = nil

                var uploadTask : NSURLSessionUploadTask = manager.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: tempFileUrl, progress: &progress, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(tempFileUrl, error: nil)
                    if let err = error {
                        println("There was an error :(")
                        println("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        // TODO: Add in relevant error catching
                        successCallback(success: false)
                    } else {
                        successCallback(success: true)
                    }
                })

                if let testNil = progress {
                    progressCallback(progress: progress)
                }

                uploadTask.resume()
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func multipleFileUploadRequestSessionManager(url:String,parameters:NSDictionary,fileInfo:NSArray,completionHandler: (response:NSURLResponse?,responseObject:AnyObject?,error:NSError?) -> ())
    {
        let request : NSMutableURLRequest = AFHTTPRequestSerializer().multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: url, parameters: parameters, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) -> Void in

            if(fileInfo.count > 0)
            {
                for file in fileInfo
                {
                    var fileData    = file.valueForKey("fileData") as NSData
                    var name        = file.valueForKey("filenameData") as String
                    var fileName    = file.valueForKey("fileName") as String
                    var mimeType    = file.valueForKey("mimeType") as String

                    formData.appendPartWithFileData(fileData, name: name, fileName: fileName, mimeType: mimeType)
                }
            }


        }, error: nil)

        let conf : NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let manager : AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: conf)

        var progress : NSProgress? = nil

        var uploadTask:NSURLSessionUploadTask = manager.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil) { (response, responseObject, error) -> Void in
            completionHandler(response:response,responseObject:responseObject,error:error)

        }

        uploadTask.resume()
}
```

This might help you for multiple file upload